# Azure AD Connection with ODBC

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, odbc

I’m trying to connect Alteryx with an ODBC to Snowflake using Azure Active Directory. To my surprise it doesn’t work and support tells me that it isn’t supported.
Anyone found any workaround to connect with an ODBC to Snowflake using Azure AD?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

At present,it is really not supported to connect Alteryx to snowflakes using ODBC using Azure Active Directory.So there is no way to do that.